# How to Limit the Amount of PHP showed in view?

Tags: php

Right now i am displaying the table in PHP but i don't want to do that i want to limit the view to mostly HTML and only small amount of php. is there any good way to do this?

is there any way to do this?

```
   echo"<table border='0' class='content-display'>
        <tr>
        <th class='table-header'>Name</th>
        <th class='table-header'>Date</th>
        <th class='table-header'>Protected</th>
        <th class='table-header'>Final</th>
        <th class='table-header'>Make New</th>
       </tr>";


                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)){

                        $name= $row['name'];
                        $date= $row['date'];
                        $pro= $row['protected'];
                        $fianl= $row['final'];


                        echo"<tr>
                            <td>
                                $name
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                $date
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                $pro
                            </td>
                            <form method='post' action='check.php'>
                            <td>

                                    <input type='text' name='viewkey' value='$name' hidden >

                                    <button class='main-buttons' type='submit'>Create Time Entry</button>

                            </td>
                            </form> 
                            <form method='post' action='check.php'>
                            <td>

                                    <input type='text' name='viewkey' value='1' hidden >
                                    <input type='text' name='proname' value='2' hidden >
                                    <button class='main-buttons' type='submit'>View Checks</button>


                            </td>
                            </form>
                        </tr>";

                    }


        echo"</table>";
```

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: Consider using a framework, or looking into design patterns like MVC. Also, using a template engine like Twig would help. You have several options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand your question i think you want something like this:

```
<table border='0' class='content-display'>
    <tr>
        <th class='table-header'>Name</th>
        <th class='table-header'>Date</th>
        <th class='table-header'>Protected</th>
        <th class='table-header'>Final</th>
        <th class='table-header'>Make New</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)) {
        $name  = $row['name'];
        $date  = $row['date'];
        $pro   = $row['protected'];
        $fianl = $row['final'];
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $pro; ?></td>
            <td>
                <form method='post' action='check.php'>
                    <input type='text' name='viewkey' value='<?php echo $name; ?>' hidden >
                    <button class='main-buttons' type='submit'>Create Time Entry</button>
                </form> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method='post' action='check.php'>
                    <input type='text' name='viewkey' value='1' hidden >
                    <input type='text' name='proname' value='2' hidden >
                    <button class='main-buttons' type='submit'>View Checks</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

But you should realy take Seer's comment in consideration.

Comment: You and I were sitting and cleaning his code at the same time eyh? ;)

Comment: Well, could have spared me some time :-)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to enclose all of your HTML inside an echo statement. 
You can close and open php tags as much as you'd like. This makes the code easier to read and the mix is much better.

Consider the following file code compared to yours:

```
 <table border='0' class='content-display'>
    <tr>
        <th class='table-header'>Name</th>
        <th class='table-header'>Date</th>
        <th class='table-header'>Protected</th>
        <th class='table-header'>Final</th>
        <th class='table-header'>Make New</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)):

        $name= $row['name'];
        $date= $row['date'];
        $pro= $row['protected'];
        $fianl= $row['final'];
                                            ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $pro; ?></td>
            <td>
                <form method='post' action='check.php'>
                    <input type='text' name='viewkey' value='<?php echo $name; ?>' hidden >
                    <button class='main-buttons' type='submit'>Create Time Entry</button>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method='post' action='check.php'>
                    <input type='text' name='viewkey' value='1' hidden >
                    <input type='text' name='proname' value='2' hidden >
                    <button class='main-buttons' type='submit'>View Checks</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just separate the php code and HTML code as 
table border='0' class='content-display'>
<tr>
    <th class='table-header'>Name</th>
    <th class='table-header'>Date</th>
    <th class='table-header'>Protected</th>
    <th class='table-header'>Final</th>
    <th class='table-header'>Make New</th>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)) {
    $name  = $row['name'];
    $date  = $row['date'];
    $pro   = $row['protected'];
    $fianl = $row['final'];
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pro; ?></td>
        <td>
            <form method='post' action='check.php'>
                <input type='text' name='viewkey' value='<?php echo $name; ?>' hidden >
                <button class='main-buttons' type='submit'>Create Time Entry</button>
            </form> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method='post' action='check.php'>
                <input type='text' name='viewkey' value='1' hidden >
                <input type='text' name='proname' value='2' hidden >
                <button class='main-buttons' type='submit'>View Checks</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```